# Error while merging multiple dex files (Android Studio and Flutter)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-multidex

When I build my project, I keep getting this error about some dex files that could not be merged.

I've tried migrating to AndroidX but when I do that, it says that I have no AndroidX usages. I've deleted the .gradle file, I've run 'flutter clean', I've closed and opened Android Studio again and nothing. Also, I've tried the 'solutions' to similiar previously asked questions about this kind of issue.

THESE ARE MY DEPENDENCIES:

---

```
name: animal_recog
description: 

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_facebook_login: ^1.1.1
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  json_annotation: ^2.0.0
  image_picker: 0.4.12+1
  flutter_auth_buttons:
  camera: ^0.2.9+1
  path_provider: 0.4.1
  multi_image_picker: 4.3.6

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^1.0.0
  json_serializable: ^2.0.0
```

THIS IS THE COMPLETE ERROR LOG:

---

D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

  > `Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
  >   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/0.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/1.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/2.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/3.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/8.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/9.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/10.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/11.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/12.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/13.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/14.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/15.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/16.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/17.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/18.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/19.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/20.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/21.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/22.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/23.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/24.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/25.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/26.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/27.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/28.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/29.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/30.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/31.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/32.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/33.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/34.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/35.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/36.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/37.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/38.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/39.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/40.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/41.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/42.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/43.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/44.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/45.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/46.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/47.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/48.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/49.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/50.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/51.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/52.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/53.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/54.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/55.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/56.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/57.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/58.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/59.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/60.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/61.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/62.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/63.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/64.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/65.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/66.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/67.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/68.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/69.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/70.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/71.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/72.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/73.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/74.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/75.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/76.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/77.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/78.jar, /Users/gabrielspranger/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/animal_recog/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/79.jar
  >   Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  >   Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver`
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at (url)

BUILD FAILED in 23s

---

The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
See (URL) for more information on the problem and how to fix it.

---

Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: What is your `minSdkVersion`? You can this at `android/app/build.gradle`.

Comment: minSdkVersion 21

Comment: Have you tried enabling multidex for your project?

Comment: Yes and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: According to your logs it is asking you to go to `https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes`. Have you cross verified any of the case mentioned there are not the ones with you?

Answer (score 1):

try adding this to your app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {

    multiDexEnabled true  

}

dependencies {

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

}

i had the same issue and i was able to fix it this way, plus i migrated to androidx manually.

Comment: @Gabriel S please confirm if this solution worked for you, and check it so can anyone facing this problem sees it.